# How can I create a correlation matrix from 2 vectors of its upper and lower triangle in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two vectors, each one corresponding to one half of a correlation matrix. Say,

```
a = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6]
b = [0.11 0.22 0.33 0.44 0.55 0.66]
```

What I'd like to do is assemble them in a matrix like this one:

```
correlation_matrix = [1     0.1  0.2  0.3
                      0.11  1    0.4  0.5   <-- a
             b -->    0.22  0.44 1    0.6
                      0.33  0.55 0.66 1]
```

Is there a function that does it in python?

Comment: https://medium.com/@sebastiannorena/finding-correlation-between-many-variables-multidimensional-dataset-with-python-5deb3f39ffb3 use pandas

Comment: I calculate the MIC using the minepy module. I've already used the ```DataFrame.corr()``` function, but the MIC method isn't available...

Comment: I have edited my answer with a method for switching the positions of the 0.33 and 0.44, which was wrong in my original answer.

Comment: That's exactly a comment that I had done but I deleted it since I found a way to arrive at the output I needed (although your way is more efficient). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for confirming - I've completely removed the original solution from my answer, just in case anyone else stumbles across this in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6])
b = np.array([0.11, 0.22, 0.33, 0.44, 0.55, 0.66])
```

First set the size you expect for your final correlation matrix, and create an identity matrix:

```
n = 4
results = np.identity(n)
```

Get upper triangle indices and assign values of `a`. Switch the row and column indices around and assign values of `b`:

```
rows, cols = np.triu_indices(n, 1)  # The 1 denotes offset from diagonal
results[rows, cols] = a
results[cols, rows] = b
```

Results:

```
array([[1.  , 0.1 , 0.2 , 0.3 ],
       [0.11, 1.  , 0.4 , 0.5 ],
       [0.22, 0.44, 1.  , 0.6 ],
       [0.33, 0.55, 0.66, 1.  ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a basic for loop and if statement :

```
a = [0.1, 0.2 ,0.3,0.4 ,0.5 ,0.6]
b = [0.11, 0.22, 0.33 ,0.44, 0.55 ,0.66]

count_a = 0
count_b = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        if j == i :
            print ("{:<5}".format(1), end = " ")
        elif (i>j):
            print ("{:<5}".format(b[count_b]), end = " ")
            count_b += 1
        elif (i<j):
            print ("{:<5}".format(a[count_a]), end = " ")
            count_a += 1
    print()
```

output:

```
1     0.1   0.2   0.3   
0.11  1     0.4   0.5   
0.22  0.33  1     0.6   
0.44  0.55  0.66  1
```

EDIT:

```
a = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
b = [0.11, 0.22, 0.33, 0.44, 0.55, 0.66]

Matrix = []
count_a = 0
count_b = 0
for i in range(4):
    row = []
    for j in range(4):
        if j == i:
            row.append(1)
        elif (i > j):
            row.append(b[count_b])
            count_b += 1
        elif (i < j):
            row.append(a[count_a])
            count_a += 1
    Matrix.append(row)

print (Matrix)
```

output:

```
[[1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], 
[0.11, 1, 0.4, 0.5], 
[0.22, 0.33, 1, 0.6], 
[0.44, 0.55, 0.66, 1]]
```

or:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.matrix(Matrix))
```

output:

```
[[1.   0.1  0.2  0.3 ]
 [0.11 1.   0.4  0.5 ]
 [0.22 0.33 1.   0.6 ]
 [0.44 0.55 0.66 1.  ]]
```

Comment: I think this answer would be better if it output a `numpy.array`, since I think that's what OP wants. I suppose OP could modify this to do that though.

Comment: I didn't notice in OPs post that he note that he wanted numpy.array ? @HS-nebula

Comment: OP wants a matrix, which I think is generally represented in Python using numpy or a list of lists. I guess OP could specify that more clearly, but I think that such a representation would be more useful that printing out strings. Unless OP's purpose is to display the matrix like so :)

Comment: if you check my edits, converting to the matrix is not a big problem ;) @HS-nebula